# Wordpress - SSO Login with LinkedIn

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, linkedin-api

I'm following the LinkedIn API details,

I have the following on my HTML page:

`<script type="in/Login"></script>`

I have included the LinkedIn details in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:XXXXXXXXXX
    authorize:false
    lang:en_US
</script>
```

This displays the pop up and asks you for your LinkedIn Username and Password.

How is this then linked to  Wordpress user? Really unsure on how to implement this so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've barely scratched the surface.  You'd be better of *either* using this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/linkedin-login/ - or else at least download it and see how they have accomplished what you are trying to do.

Comment: @cale_b - that plugin doesn't do anything once you enter your linked in username / password. Just redirects to the homepage and I'm still logged out

Comment: @nsilva: are you looking for what's called a Single Sign On? A user is able to login into both your WordPress site and LinkedIn with the same login/password?

Comment: That is correct @markratledge - don't see how there could be any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for what's called SSO - Single Sign-On. That's where a user can login to both LinkedIn and your WordPress site with the same username/password.

It's probably best to try a plugin rather than reinvent the wheel and learn the LinkedIn API and authorization procedures. Check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/

Comment: Perfect, would have never of came across this plugin, does exactly what I need!